# Sending stream via socket

Tags: c#, sockets, stream

Sorry for this type of question but I am writing a test soon on this and have no clue on the following possible question:
A web server uses the following c#-code fragment to write a static web-object into the socket-object 'sock'. For which type of web-objects does the code work and which it doesn't?  With what .Net-class could the code be improved?

```
...
f = new FileStream(pathName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(f);
sReader.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
String s = sReader.ReadlLine();
while (s != null)
{
  sock.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
  s = sReader.ReadLine();
}
sReader.Close();
...
```

Comment: The data will work with Ascii Encoding which means that non printable characters will be automatically filtered from results.   The file also must have standard windows returns at end of each line.  With a stream you have to read the entire file before using your while loop because a stream will read in blocks and you could get a null before the entire file is read.  The null indicates you reached the end of the stream not the end of the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's a "web-object"? I think your teacher made that term up. I assume this means "file".

Anyway, this will fail if the content is not exactly representable as ASCII.

There is no need to go through text at all. Just copy over the bytes:

```
f.CopyTo(new NetworkStream(sock));
```

Any other way to copy the bytes unmodified is also fine.

Be aware that you need to wrap resources such as all those streams and sockets into `using` in order to not leak.